# Configure Apache Ranger web context path to /ranger

Tags: bash, nginx, amazon-ec2, apache-ranger

I have been trying to find configuration for Apache Ranger where I'll be able to access Ranger via http://localhost/ranger rather than http:localhost:6080.

I am using NGINX and below is my NGINX configuration for ranger

```
location /ranger/ {
     proxy_pass http://localhost:6080;
}
```

I have configured Ranger on an EC2 machine and it is placed in

> /usr/local/ranger-admin

I updated the property value **ranger.contextName** from **/** to **/ranger** in the below file

> /usr/local/ranger-admin/conf/ranger-admin-default-site.xml

I could not find a way to set the context path in **install.properties** file as well. Is there a way to set the context path.

Comment: hey, were you able to find solution for this?

Comment: @chitenderkumar  Yes. I used NGINX to load ranger. Place an Nginx config file to "/etc/nginx/default.d/" with content

location /ranger/ {
         proxy_pass http://localhost:6080/;
}
now when you hit ec2-instance-ip/ranger you'll see ranger will be loaded.